# Error while using StringsAsFactors

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dataset

I am reading a dataset from CSV file like below:

```
df1=read.csv("train.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

And I am copying those values of the 1st column in dataframe to another dataframe like below:

```
link<-data.frame((df1[,1]))
```

When I try to access the values in link, it is in the form of factors:

> 'data.frame': 12 obs. of  1 variable:  $ X.df1...1..: Factor w/ 12
>   levels
>   "http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/09/apache-kafka-for-beginners/",..:
>   9 10 8 12 7 5 6 4 1 2 ...

Even though I used `StringsAsFactors=FALSE`, I am confused why these values have been stored in the form of Factors instead of characters. PLease let me know how to store these values in the form of Factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default setting of `data.frame()` is `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`. Hence, even if you read `df1` with `read.csv()` using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` the factors are re-inserted by using `data.frame()`. It is not necessary to call `data.frame()` in this case. You can just use

```
link <- df1[,1,drop=FALSE]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can verify that `df1[, 1]` is a character vector. But then you need another `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` inside `data.frame(df1[, 1])`. Have a read on `?data.frame`; by default it recodes strings as factors, too.

However, why not simply do `link <- df1[1]`?